# Why are these thumbnails different resolutions?

Tags: iphone, photos, photos.app

These are the thumbnails of the same photo in my Camera Roll and Photo Stream:

[image]

Notice that the one on the left is “fuzzier”. Zoom in on the spots on the tablecloth or the text on the book cover for example.

All photos I take are the same. This is on an iPhone 8, with iOS 12.4.1 and I don’t use iCloud Photo Library.

Is there a technical reason for this, or is it simply a bug?

Comment: I'm confused about why you have 2 thumbnails? Did you take 2 pictures? What exactly are you showing? Forgive me for not understanding better.

Comment: @jmh they might be in two albums. OP: I would not be worried if the photo itself is fine. Thumbnails are representative only.

Comment: @jmh if you take a photo it appears in your Camera Roll and your Photo Stream.

Comment: That's strange why they are different!  You'd think it would be the same image.  I see why you questioned this.